# Reverse for 'detail_view' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 11}' not found - ( Using Slug field )

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Error.

**What i am trying to do :-**

I just add `slug` into my model and also updated `get_absolute_url` and `url`.

BUT after that whenever i try to open page in browser then it shows

> Reverse for 'detail_view' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 11}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['detail_view/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P[0-9]+)$']

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail_view',kwargs={'pk':self.pk,'slug':self.slug})
```

views.py

```
def detail_view(request,pk,slug):
    data = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
```

urls.py

```
 path('detail_view/<slug:slug>/<int:pk>',views.detail_view,name='detail_view'),
```

template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'detail_view' pk=topic.pk  %}">More</a><br>
```

I have no idea what is causing this error.

Any help would be Appreciated Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have also to provide `slug` in template `url` tag `slug=topic.slug`:

```
<a href="{% url 'detail_view' slug=topic.slug pk=topic.pk  %}">More</a><br>
```

or use `get_absolute_url` method of your model:

```
<a href="{{ topic.get_absolute_url }}">More</a><br>
```

Comment: BUT it is showing **http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail_view/None/12** instead of `name of post`. Can you tell me Why ?

Comment: @Smith, Because your slug is `None`. Provide default value for your `SlugField`.

Comment: @Smith, you can also add slug in the `save()` method of the model.